# How can I access variables inside a not_if in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to chef so I might be doing something really wrong here. The question is, how do I access the `LOG_DIR` in the ruby block. I want to use `LOG_DIR` in quite a few places in my recipe.

```
LOG_DIR = "/var/log/cas"

ruby_block 'check logs' do
   block { ... }
   not_if do
      print(LOG_DIR)
      # The line above does not work.
      # NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Chef::Recipe:0x0000000003ac5f78>>::RESULT
      result = shell_out("ls #{LOG_DIR} | wc -l").stdout
      result == '0'
   end
end
```

The things that come to mind are to use `node.run_state` or/and use a lazy block. But I'm not sure how I would go about it or if it would achieve what I want.

A comment on if the lines below that have any problems would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using variables in `not_if` blocks is straightforward. But it should be for evaluation of true/false conditions. If the condition passed within `not_if { .. }` returns `true` or `0` then the Chef resource will be skipped.

> Prevent a resource from executing when the condition returns `true`.

Another thing I would like to point out is that any variables starting with a capital letter in Ruby are [constants](https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/07/ruby-constants/). So first thing I would do is, have the variable as `log_dir`.

Also, instead of doing variable assignment (`result =`) inside the `not_if` block, I would do it outside. Or even better just directly create an expression that would evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Example:

```rb
log_dir = '/var/log/cas'

ruby_block 'check logs' do
  block do
    # some code
  end
  not_if { shell_out("ls #{log_dir} | wc -l").stdout.to_i == 0 }
end
```

Or in a more Ruby'ish way:

```rb
log_dir = '/var/log/cas'

ruby_block 'check logs' do
  block do
    # some code
  end
  not_if { Dir.empty?(log_dir) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Got quite a bit of insight, My question still is, why do I get the `uninitialized constant` error when it looks clearly initialized? 
And the `LOG_DIR` looks like valid case for a constant to me as it should not change. Sorry I called it a variable in the question. New to Ruby you see. :)

Comment: Actually since we are using Chef, we might as well *avoid using Ruby variables/constants*, and use attributes instead, which are the variables of Chef - like `node['my_cookbook']['log_dir'] = '/var/log/cas'`.